# Input Button not working on Jquery form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I use the following or similar setup on all my code. I realise that if you skip ALL fields and only enter the last field, no matter what the last field is.. the form submits.. I want to prevent the form submitting if the details (flag is 1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JS</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="m2mform" id="m2mform" method="post" onsubmit="return form()" >
u:<input id="user" name="user" type="text" value="">
email:<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="">
<input class="submitx" type="button" onClick="javascript:form();"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
flag = 1;
function form() {
    if (document.getElementById("user").value == "") {
        // slidedown some red css
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        // dont show red css 
        flag = 0;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") {
        // slidedown some red css
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        // dont show red css 
        flag = 0;
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        // dont submit form
    }
    else {
        var submitForm;
        submitForm = document.getElementById("m2mform");
        submitForm.submit();
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated with another attempt:

```
var flag = 0;
function nValidateForm() {
    var flag = 0;
    if (document.getElementById("fullname").value == "") {
        $('#fullnamefail').slideDown("fast");
        flag = 1;
    }
    else {
        $('#fullnamefail').slideUp("fast");
        flag = 0;
    }

    if (flag == 1) {
        $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var custForm;
        custForm = document.getElementById("m2mform");
        custForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. You must not lower the flag (change to 0) if it's already raised (equal to 1). In addition, you should not directly call `submit()` again, just return true or false.

Fix with minimal changes to your original code:

```
flag = 0; //lower by default
if (document.getElementById("user").value == "") {
    // slidedown some red css
    flag = 1;
} else {
    // dont show red css 
}

if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") {
    // slidedown some red css
    flag = 1;
} else {
    // dont show red css 
}
if (flag == 1) {
    // dont submit form
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

This simply set the flag to 0 only once, on top, and any validation error cause the flag to be raised.

This will work, but as you're already using jQuery consider using its power.. just Google for "jQuery form validation" for very powerful and simple ways to validate user input.

Comment: you just forgot that this will end up in recursion, as `onsubmit="return form()"` will call the method `form`, which calls `submitForm.submit()` which calls the onSubmit-handler again...

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I didn't notice the way he calls the function.. answer edited.

Comment: I marked this answer as OK. My new JS code:http://www.gc-cdn.com/assets/js/m2m_c.js my new page: http://www.gorgeouscouture.com/new.m2m.php  - However in future I will be using the codes above as they are true jQuery

Comment: Cheers, when you redesign the page consider using jQuery plugin for the validation, this way you won't have to write any JS code apart of something like `$("#m2mform").validate();`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a `return false;` here ... and rather use `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"` (you do not need to declare the method-call of `form()` twice, if you'd correctly use the type `submit`)

eg with type `button`:

```
<form method="post" onSubmit="return form();">
    u:<input id="user" type="text" value=""><br />
    email:<input id="email" type="text" value=""><br />
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="submit" onClick="window.submitFromButton();" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.form = function(sender) {
    var $user = $('#user');
    var $email = $('#email');
    $user.css('background-color', 'white');
    $email.css('background-color', 'white');
    var submitTheForm = true;
    if (!$user.val()) {
        $user.css('background-color', 'red');
        submitTheForm = false;
    }
    if (!$email.val()) {
        $email.css('background-color', 'red');
        submitTheForm = false;
    }
    return submitTheForm;
};
window.submitFromButton = function() {
    var $form = $('form');
    $form.submit();
}
</script>
```

see my working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cjQ7F/)
see my working example with style [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cjQ7F/1/)
see my working example with type `button` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cjQ7F/2/)

Comment: plus this is not feesable as return false and return true on all if end blocks would not work - that is the full code: http://www.gc-cdn.com/assets/js/m2m_c.js

Comment: can you see what is wrong with my current code as show above: http://www.gc-cdn.com/assets/js/m2m_c.js

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid you'd need to call a different method on the button-click ... otherwise just change to type `submit` on remove the onClick-handler from the submit-button

Answer (score 0):

To cancel the event firing, you need to `return false;` when you do not want to submit your form in your `form()` function:

```
<input class="submitx" type="button" onClick="javascript:form();"/>

function form() {

    ....    

    if (flag == 1) {
        return false;  // this will cancel the click event firing on the submit button
    }
    else {
        var submitForm;
        submitForm = document.getElementById("m2mform");
        submitForm.submit();
    }
}
```